# web application - where to place hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate.cfg.xml

I am writing a web application and I have to add hibernate. I configured maven (pom.xml) etc. but now I am getting the following error:

```
exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

I am using NetBeans. I tried moving this file to WEB-INF, root project folder, src directory (default package) but it's still not working. How can I do? I don't want to set path to this file programmatically like this:

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.addResource("/some/path/to/this/file/Hibernate.cfg.xml");
```

Comment: It should be at the root of the classpath.

Comment: Btw: how can I check classpath?

Comment: What do you mean by "check classpath"?

Comment: Ohh my mistake, it should be "how can I check what is the root of the classpath?"

Comment: For a web app you don't have to, it's defined by the servlet spec, and is `WEB-INF/classes`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I always put it into `WEB-INF/classes` directory (compiled files are stored there).

Comment: Thanks, I created classes directory in WEB-INF and it's working fine.

Comment: Odd that you had to -create- that directory. You have at least one class that needs to go there! Methinks you are not using Netbeans properly here, but I can only guess.

Comment: @user1946059 It seems like this answer is what you were looking for -- you should accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the hibernate.cfg.xml to a folder in the classpath. In a webb app, WEB-INF/classes is in the classpath by default. You can either use that folder or create a new one for your resources (assuming you want to keep them separate) and then set the new folder in classpath by adjusting your project settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can load hibernate.cfg.xml from a different directory (not necessarily the classpath) using the configure(File configFile) method that takes the hibernateConfig File argument.
(note, am using hibernate 4.3.7)

The advantage is, you can place your hibernate configs file in a separate directory which you are bound to have access to (for maintenance or change purposes) other than bundling it together with the .war file which you may not have access to.

Example follows:

---

```
String hibernatePropsFilePath = "/etc/configs/hibernate.cfg.xml";
File hibernatePropsFile = new File(hibernatePropsFilePath);

Configuration configuration = new Configuration(); 
configuration.configure(hibernatePropsFile);

StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();

SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

This file must be in the root of classpath of the application. That is under WEB-INF/classes

Comment: the file does not necessarily need to be in your classpath. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27666320/1547266